# Windows Perl - Win32::Systray and IO::Socket::Multicast - how to get them work together?

Tags: windows, perl, sockets

Hi stackoverflow community!

I am trying to make Win32::Systray and IO::Socket::Multicast work together in one script. But I just can't for a week haha!

**1st target:** make a system tray with buttons (Options/Exit/Other stuff).
**2nd target:** listen for port communication and execute actions once any communication received.

**The problem:** Once one of them will execute (like the Win32::Systray), the script loops on either the systray or the port listener (like a loop, I did not review the module itself - lazy).
For the Muticast too, its on loop, that is the end of it. It wont continue to below of the script (obviously its a endless loop, it will loop there).

**What I need:** I want to make a systray icon that will fuction properly when I click it (showing buttons) and in the same time, listening to port communication with no conflicts on both.

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------
# Perl Modules
#---------------------------------------------------------------
# use strict;
# use warnings;
use IO::Socket::Multicast;
#use IO::Socket::INET;
use Win32;
use Win32::GUI;
use Win32::SysTray;
use Win32::Process;
use File::Basename;
use File::Spec::Functions qw[ catfile rel2abs updir ];
use Tk;

my $domain_cfg = rel2abs(dirname($0)).'\cfg\site_domain.cfg';
open(FH, '<', $domain_cfg) or die $!;
while(<FH>){
    $domain = $_;
}
close(FH);

print "domain_file:$domain_cfg\n";
print "domain:$domain\n";

#---------------------------------------------------------------
# SysTray
#---------------------------------------------------------------

my $tray = new Win32::SysTray (
    'icon' => rel2abs(dirname($0)).'\img\server.ico', #\\Demosai DIR
    'single' => 1,
    'name' => $title,
    'tip'  => 'test'
) or exit 0; 

$tray->setMenu (
    "> Option" => sub { 
        print "LOL!\n";
    },
    ">-"      => 0,
    "> Exit" => sub { 
        terminate();
    },
); 

#$tray->runApplication;
$tray->runApplication unless fork;

#---------------------------------------------------------------
# Wait and Read Port
#---------------------------------------------------------------

$default_port = '3671';

$default_reply_ip = '00.00.00.00';
$default_reply_port = '3672';
$default_reply = 'MESSAGE_RECEIVED';

print "Running Comms... Port [$default_port]\n";

# Create a new multicast UDP socket ready to read datagrams sent to port 3671
my $s = IO::Socket::Multicast->new(LocalPort=>$default_port);

# Add a multicast group address
$s->mcast_add('00.00.00.00');

# Optionally, the address can be associated with a specific network adapter
# $s->mcast_add('00.00.00.00','eth0');

$tmp_ctr = 0;

my $data;
while (1) {


    # Wait until a packet is received
    $s->recv($data,1024);

    print "Data received: ".length($data)." = $data\n";
  
    #---------------------------------------------------------------
    # REPLY
    #---------------------------------------------------------------
    print "Replying...";
    #$s->mcast_send($default_reply,$default_reply_ip);
}

#---------------------------------------------------------------
# END OF FILE
#---------------------------------------------------------------
print "EOF\n";
```

Comment: Two threads and/or two processes.